# Python pandas count specific statistic

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame in pandas which looks like this:

```
| index | order_id | product_id | user_id | days_since_prior_order | order_number |
|-------|----------|------------|---------|------------------------|--------------|
| 0     | 177      | 21903      | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 1     | 177      | 40723      | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 2     | 177      | 27531      | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 3     | 177      | 1158       | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 4     | 177      | 37766      | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 5     | 177      | 48299      | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 6     | 177      | 46802      | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 7     | 177      | 38159      | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 8     | 177      | 35055      | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 9     | 177      | 40311      | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 10    | 177      | 5022       | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 11    | 177      | 19906      | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 12    | 177      | 29987      | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 13    | 177      | 9076       | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 14    | 177      | 43352      | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 15    | 177      | 33731      | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 16    | 177      | 24852      | 48308   | 8.0                    | 27           |
| 17    | 220      | 3919       | 63952   | 6.0                    | 26           |
| 18    | 220      | 11432      | 63952   | 6.0                    | 26           |
| 19    | 220      | 14992      | 63952   | 6.0                    | 26           |
| 20    | 378      | 13249      | 128710  | 2.0                    | 66           |
| 21    | 378      | 43693      | 128710  | 2.0                    | 66           |
| 22    | 946      | 1529       | 157339  | 3.0                    | 10           |
| 23    | 946      | 20734      | 157339  | 3.0                    | 10           |
| 24    | 946      | 22935      | 157339  | 3.0                    | 10           |
| 25    | 946      | 26728      | 157339  | 3.0                    | 10           |
```

This is not the full dataset, just small part of the table.
What I want to do is count mean days between product reorder for each user. So for each user we take all orders which contain the specific product_id and then calculate time between these orders (including other orders without this product) ((we use order_number to determine orders' order)) and then take mean of that. I want to do it with pandas because the dataset is very big and I don't have so many RAM and resources to calculate that using classic python code. How can I do that?

Edit:
I seem not to be clear enough. What i want is when user orders a product multiple times count days between this product orders and for every product Id calculate mean. So i want to know how ofter is the product ordered.

Edit 2:
I made a csv for one user so you could take a look at how this df looks like :[df_for_one_user.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/363ih9zj0tep1xk/df_for_one_user.csv?dl=0)

Edit 3: "days_since_prior_order" is just days between this and previous order for user. The problem is that between could be an order without specific product.

Comment: The sample you posted here does not contain any "reorder" I think? And in my experience, using pandas does not save you any memory (in fact it could get worse for some operations like pivot).

Comment: @Mephy I believe it to be more optimized then any code I write ;)
This table is just and example. I cannot post whole dataset here. The idea is that user can order the product multiple times and I want to know how many days passed between those times.

Comment: what I find confusion is the fact that days_since_prior_order seems constant for each (user, product pair)... can you maybe provide a more relevant example?

Comment: @FLab they are not constant from order_id to order_id. I'll try to find something more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the groupby method of dataframes.

```
df.groupby(['user_id','product_id'])['days_since_prior_order'].mean()
```

Will return the average time since prior order per unique user id for each product id that customer has ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you want, but something similar to

```
df.groupby(['user_id','product_id'])['days_since_prior_order'].mean()
```

Comment: This wil just give me mean of the column